# python Memory Management for functions

Tags: python, function, memory

```
import sys
import gc

def func_a(a,b,c):
    print(a,b,c)

def func_b():
    print("b")

a = func_b()
b = func_a(1,2,3)
print(id(a) == id(b))
print(a is b)

class c_1():
    def __init__(self) -&gt; None:
        pass

class c_2():
    def __init__(self) -&gt; None:
        pass

c1 = c_1()
c2 = c_2()
print(id(c1) == id(c2))
print(c1 is c2)
```

output:

```
b
1 2 3
True
True
False
False
```

Any idea why a is equal to b? when i add `return 1` or not None return to a, a is not equal to b. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't understand the underlying thought process here. What do you think the question has to do with "memory management"? What do you think that means, in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Your functions do not explicitly return anything. Therefore they implicitly return None. Thus both *a* and *b* are equal to None